# Extract part of JSON response in Python

Tags: python, json, api

I'm a beginner in programming, and I'm trying to deal with an API to automate my work.

I'm getting the response just fine, but I'm only interested by 2 values, being host and port.

Here is a part of my code

```
import requests

url = "https://proxy6.net/api/xxx"

def descr():
    return 88


querystring = {"descr":descr()}

headers = {
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "xxx"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)

print(response.text)
```

How can I print only the host and port value?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: You mean the host your script is running on, or proxy6.net? And do you expect a port other than 443?

Comment: Can you post what the output of the request is? It is good that you have excluded the API key from the code, but without it the example can not be reproduced.

Comment: `{"status":"yes","user_id":"xx","balance":"xx","currency":"xx","list_count":1,"list":{"xx":{"id":"xx","version":"x,"ip":"xx","host":"xx","port":xx","user":"xx","pass":"xx","type":"socks","country":"us","date":"2018-09-05 22:00:22","date_end":"2018-10-05 22:00:22","unixtime":1536174022,"unixtime_end":1538766022,"descr":"88","active":"1"}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
response = requests.request(...)
data = response.json()
for value in data['list'].values():
    host = value['host']
    port = value['port']

    print host, port  # OP uses Python 2

    break
else:  # we didn't break, which means data['list'] was empty
    raise RuntimeError('Empty list')

response2 = requests.request('POST', ...)  # you can use host and port here
```

Comment: Alright, getting this back:

`(u'168.235.xx.xx', u'23xxx')`
Will there be a way to extract those too and implement it into another post request?

Comment: I assumed you're using Python 3 (which you really should btw), in Python 2 you should omit the parentheses in the `print` statement and you'll get the output you want.

Comment: Using Python 2. Thanks a lot for your help.
I'll now try to implement it with the second piece of code I have (trying to link 2 APIs)

Comment: Thanks. This is the piece of code I have for my other API I want to make the link with.

`payload = "{\n\t\"generateZeroFingerprintsData\": true,\n    \"name\": \"descr\",\n    
`

Removed a whole part, but I would like here, for example, to set the name to what I defined with descr. I don't recognize the format of it tho, which kind of blocks me.

Comment: Might need help on that one also, it seems that it's a format issue. Trying to do it this way `\"name\": \""descr()"\"` but it says invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://proxy6.net/api/xxx"

def descr():
    return 88


querystring = {"descr":descr()}

headers = {
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
    'Postman-Token': "xxx"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, params=querystring)
response = response.json()
print(response['list']['xx']['host'])
print(response['list']['xx']['port'])
```

Explanations:

```
{"status":"yes","user_id":"xx","balance":"xx","currency":"xx","list_count":1,"list":{"xx":{"id":"xx","version":"x,"ip":"xx","host":"xx","port":xx","user":"xx","pass":"xx","type":"socks","country":"us","date":"2018-09-05 22:00:22","date_end":"2018-10-05 22:00:22","unixtime":1536174022,"unixtime_end":1538766022,"descr":"88","active":"1"}}}


response['list'] gives `{"xx":{"id":"xx","version":"x,"ip":"xx","host":"xx","port":xx","user":"xx","pass":"xx","type":"socks","country":"us","date":"2018-09-05 22:00:22","date_end":"2018-10-05 22:00:22","unixtime":1536174022,"unixtime_end":1538766022,"descr":"88","active":"1"}}`


response['list']['xx']  gives  `{"id":"xx","version":"x,"ip":"xx","host":"xx","port":xx","user":"xx","pass":"xx","type":"socks","country":"us","date":"2018-09-05 22:00:22","date_end":"2018-10-05 22:00:22","unixtime":1536174022,"unixtime_end":1538766022,"descr":"88","active":"1"}`

response['list']['xx']['host'] gives host key value
response['list']['xx']['port'] gives port key value
```

Do let me know if you have doubts

Comment: Getting a KeyError with that one

Comment: Check now @Vanity